# Constructor Specialization with Templates

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, specialization

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct MyType
{
    public:

    T cont;

    MyType(T value) : cont(value) {}
    MyType(int value = 1) : cont(value) {}
    MyType(double value = 1.2) : cont(value) {}
};

int main()
{
    MyType <int> a;

    return 0;
}
```

This code gives these errors:

> error: 'MyType::MyType(int) [with T = int]' cannot be overloaded
>
> error: with 'MyType::MyType(T) [with T = int]'

**Now, how can I specialize some constructor giving them default parameters?**

EDIT:

**I need a way to do it without copy-pasting all the class for every specialization.**

Comment: "_This code gives some errors:_" Please copy-paste said errors into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing

```
template <class T>
struct MyType
{
    public:

    T cont;

    MyType(T value) : cont(value) {}
    MyType(int value = 1) : cont(value) {}
    MyType(double value = 1.2) : cont(value) {}
};

int main()
{
    MyType <int> a;

    return 0;
}
```

you have two identical constructors `MyType(int value = 1)` and `MyType(T/*int*/ value)`, you cannot have that overloading

---

> I need a way to do it without copy-pasting all the class for every specialization.

You can have

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct MyType
{
  public:
    T cont;

    MyType(T value = 1) : cont(value) {}
};

template<>
MyType<int>::MyType(int value) : cont(value + 1) {}

template<>
MyType<double>::MyType(double value) : cont(value + 2) {}

int main()
{
  MyType <int> a;
  MyType <int> aa(10);
  MyType <double> b;

  cout << a.cont << '/' << aa.cont << '/' << b.cont << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

but you cannot specify an other default value for the parameter of the specialization (`error: default argument specified in explicit specialization [-fpermissive]`) because as usual the default value is specified in the declaration and not in the definition

Compilation and execution

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra -Wall t.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
2/11/3
```

Answer (score 2):

Simpler would probably be specialization:

```
template <class T>
struct MyType
{
public:
    T cont;

    MyType(T value) : cont(value) {}
};

template <>
struct MyType<int>
{
public:
    int cont;

    MyType(int value = 1) : cont(value) {}
};

template <>
struct MyType<double>
{
public:
    double cont;

    MyType(double value = 1.1) : cont(value) {}
};
```

Or, as it seems it is only default value your are interested in, you might tag dispatching default value:

```
template <typename T> struct tag{};

template <typename T> const T defaultValue(tag<T>) { return {}; }
inline int defaultValue(tag<int>) { return 1;}
inline double defaultValue(tag<double>) { return 1.1;}

template <class T>
struct MyType
{
public:
    T cont;

    MyType(T value = defaultValue(tag<T>)) : cont(value) {}
};
```

Comment: But isn't there a way to do it without copy-pasting all the class?